# How make an archetype generates a file named like the artifactId

Tags: java, maven, properties, maven-archetype

I have a small `ConfigurationSingleton` class which loads some properties from a configuration file named, at the moment, `configuration_singleton.xml`:

```
private ConfigurationSingleton() throws IOException {
  ...
  configurationIS = ConfigurationSingleton.class.
      getResourceAsStream("/configuration_singleton.xml");
  ...
```

The file is in the directory:

```
/
++- src
    +-- test
        +-- resources
            +-- configuration_singleton.xml
```

Now **I want to use an archetype** to generate the `my-project-1.0.0.jar` artifact which is configured by the `my-project-1.0.0.xml` file. As usual I have used a Maven properties `${artifactId}` and `${version}` here:

```
private ConfigurationSingleton() throws IOException {
  ...
  configurationIS = ConfigurationSingleton.class.
      getResourceAsStream("/${artifactId}-${version}.xml");
  ...
```

but how make the archetype generates a configuration file named like `${artifactId}-${version}.xml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As reported in the [archetype descriptor fileset](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/archetype-models/archetype-descriptor/archetype-descriptor.html#fileSet):

> If file or directory name contains `__property__` pattern, it is replaced with corresponding property value.

So you can use the `__artifactId__` and `__version__` properties in the archetype project's file system like:

```
/
+-- src
    +-- test
        +-- resources
            +-- __artifactId__-__version__.xml
```

**Summarizing**

- use `${property}` inside file
- use `__property__` inside file system